# Let MediaPlayer select a random file automatically when ended

Tags: android, kotlin, service, android-mediaplayer

I want to create a kind of soundscape. For this I have a service in which three instances of MediaPlayer are created. On completion they should select a new file for playback, play that file and repeat that process.

The following code only plays the files from `.create()` but then does not seem to do anything else. At runtime, "selectstarted" and "playstarted" are printed, so I can only guess that the mistake is somewhere in the `selectBordun()` or the `play()` function, but I have no idea where.

Please note that I have shortened the code for readability. Every time, `mPlayer` is mentioned, I have the same code two more times, just with `mPlayer2` and `mPlayer3`. But the basic principle should be the same with just one instance.

```
open class BordunService : Service() {

private lateinit var mPlayer: MediaPlayer

override fun onCreate() {
    mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.fping)
}

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {

    if (intent.hasExtra("Play")) {
                    playBordun()
                }
}

private fun playBordun() {
        fun playMPlayer() {

            mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(object: MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener  {
                override fun onCompletion(p0: MediaPlayer?) {
                    println("completem")
                    selectBordun(mPlayer)
                }
            })

             mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(object:MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {
                override fun onPrepared(p0: MediaPlayer?) {
                    println("preparedm")
                    mPlayer.start()
                }
            })
        }

        GlobalScope.launch {
            playMPlayer()
        }
    }

fun selectBordun(player: MediaPlayer) {
    println("selectstarted")
    player.reset()
    val randomGenerator = Random()
    val bordunInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(3) + 1
    when (bordunInt) {
        1 -> {
            val afd = this.getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.cping)
            afd.close()
            player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength())
//                player.prepareAsync()
            play(player)
        }
        2 -> {
            val afd = this.getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.ebping)
            afd.close()
            player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength())
//              player.prepareAsync()
            play(player)
        }
        3 -> {
            val afd = this.getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.gping)
            afd.close()
            player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength())
//            player.prepareAsync()
            play(player)
        }
    }
}

fun play(player: MediaPlayer) {
   println("playstarted")
   player.setOnPreparedListener(object:MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {
        override fun onPrepared(p0: MediaPlayer?) {
            println("preparedplayer")
            player.start()
        }
    })


    player.setOnCompletionListener(object: MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener  {
        override fun onCompletion(p0: MediaPlayer?) {
            println("completeplayer")
            selectBordun(player)
        }
    })

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I solved this using some more boilerplate code, releasing and re-creating each MediaPlayer instance with its own function, so I didn´t have to set a new data source.